# How to extract the first and last value from a txt file, in python?

Tags: python, txt

I have a txt file made like this:

```
2,5,25,6
3,5,78,6,
5,23,24,85
6,4,79,9
69,23,12,51
```

I should extract only two values that are the first value in the first line 2 and the first value in the last line 69.
The program I wrote is the following:

```
with open("C:\values.txt", "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    print(lines[i])
```

but I can only print all the lines present in the txt file.

Comment: Note, there is basically never a good reason to use `readlines`, it's a relic. File objects are iterators, your code could just be `for line in fp: print(line)`

Comment: And after being able to access each line in the for loop; then what is the next step? You could start to look at the lines[i] type and notice it's a string and not (yet) a list of numbers. Then how do you convert this string into a list of numbers? And finally, access the first number on the first line and the last number on the last line.

Comment: as output I need :
2, 69

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening the file via iostream, you can use `readlines()` to transfer the whole data to the list. And you can get the value you want with the index of the list.

```
with open("value.txt", "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    first = lines[0].split(',')[0]
    end = lines[-1].split(',')[0]

    print(first, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use indexing along with `.read()`:

```
with open(r"C:\values.txt", "r") as fp:
  txt = fp.read().strip()
  first_val = int(txt.split("\n")[0].split(",")[0])
  last_val = int(txt.split("\n")[-1].split(",")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

something like the below

```
with open("values.txt", "r") as fp:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in fp.readlines()]
    first_and_last = [lines[0], lines[-1]]
    for l in first_and_last:
        print(l.split(',')[0])
```

output

```
2
69
```